# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found - Flutter Notifications Plugin

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, macos

I am trying to run a flutter project in my Mac mini, which works perfectly for android, but I'm getting this error:
"Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/nitant/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_local_notifications-12.0.3/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.h:0:8

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max."

I have tried every solution mentioned `https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-fatal-error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found/` and others in stack overflow, but nothing seems to work. Any idea why I'm seeing this error? I also tried different versions of flutter and different package versions. Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair your pub cache: **dart pub cache repair**

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work... Same error persists.

Comment: Yeah this didn't work for me either